# Toggle menu trouble

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a toggle menu I placed an `onclick` event listener on my HTML page. The problems occur when I test out the menu, the console tells me that `uncaught ReferenceError: myFnc is not defined at HTMLDivelement.onclick`.

HTML code

```
<body>

  <header>

      <img src="img/medical.png" alt="">

      <div class="container" onclick="myFnc(this)">

          <div class="line-1"></div>

          <div class="line-2"></div>

          <div class="line-3"></div>

      </div>

      <nav>

   <ul>

       <li><a href="pages/patent.php">Patients</a></li>

       <li><a href="pages/schedule.php">Schedule</a></li>

       <li><a href="pages/notes.php">Documents</a></li>

       <li><a href="pages/email.php">E-mail</a></li>

       <li><a href="pages/register.php">Register</a></li>

       <li><a href="pages/login.php">Login</a></li>

   </ul>

      </nav>

  </header> 

  <main></main>

  <script

  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"

  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="

  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Javascript

```
function myFnc(e) {

  var elem = document.getElementsByName("nav");

  style = window.getComputedStyle("elem");

  right = style.getPropertyValue("right");


  if (right == "0px") {

    elem.style.right = "-260px";

  } else {

    elem.style.right = "0px";

  }

}
```

Comment: That code should work just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Updated for new code: better to use `document.querySelector("nav")`. documnet.getElementsByName() returns a node list, while `.querySelector` returns a single element so it's easier to work with in this case. Other than that, in `style = window.getComputedStyle("elem");`, you are passing in `"elem"`, but you should pass only `elem` (without quotation marks) as you are referencing a variable.

Here is a working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gLmzfrwd/), note that you have to use `position: relative` or `position: absolute` for the `right:-700px` to have an effect.

```js
function myFnc(e) {

  var elem = document.querySelector("nav");

  style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);

  right = style.getPropertyValue("right");


  if (right == "0px") {

    elem.style.right = "-260px";

  } else {

    elem.style.right = "0px";

  }

}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>

  <img src="img/medical.png" alt="">

  <div class="container" onclick="myFnc(this)"> CLICK ME

      <div class="line-1"></div>

      <div class="line-2"></div>

      <div class="line-3"></div>

  </div>

  <nav>

   <ul>

   <li><a href="pages/patent.php">Patients</a></li>

   <li><a href="pages/schedule.php">Schedule</a></li>

   <li><a href="pages/notes.php">Documents</a></li>

   <li><a href="pages/email.php">E-mail</a></li>

   <li><a href="pages/register.php">Register</a></li>

   <li><a href="pages/login.php">Login</a></li>

   </ul>

      </nav>

  </header> 

  <main></main>

  <script

  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"

  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="

  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Gladly, but you will need to be specific about what the problem is and provide all the code.

Comment: I added my html/ohp code and javascript code I hope you can help. I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: @user12331718 updated answer now, hope it help. Let me know if any other problems.